# dynamic remove or add fields in a structure

Tags: matlab, dynamic, structure, field

how can I read consecutive structures from a file, when they have different fields, and create for each of them the appropriate fields (title: value)? I am a beginner. I think it is about dynamic adding new fields while reading i-th structure and dynamic removing the fields from the i-1 structure, which remained empty after reading a structure i. But how am I able to do it not knowing the names of all the fields before? For this I couldn't find example in documentation nor in the forum.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some fields appear in every object, have them in a common structure that your array has instances of. For the variables fields, make a field "variable" or something in the main structure, and then dynamically assign field names and values *within* that structure. So for example, your structure might be:

```
a.name = 'Name1';
a.value = 'Value1';
a.variable.price = 50;


b.name = 'Name2';
b.value = 'Value2';
b.variable.year = 1996;

data(1) = a; data(2) = b;
```

where every object has fields "name" and "price" and object `a` has a price field but not a year field, and object `b` has a year field and no price field.

This will work for the kind of data you want to read in.

Comment: Thanks for a nice idea! However the problem here is, that I might not know how many such specific fields a structure has, so a variable price, but maybe more of them. what to do then? How to read them dynamically from this file, and then how to overwrite/delete old ones when reading new structure with new specific fields/variables ?

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue - you can put as many fields as you like within the "variable" field - you can say a.variable.price, a.variable.id, a.variable.size and any number of such sub-fields. Essentially, your main structure remains the same so you won't have to overwrite anything.

Comment: Yes I understand. So I can create array of structures (a and b) and initiate these structures with the fieldnames: name, value, variable. Then I can find appropriate words in a file, index them, using regexp take out what I want. But what I don't know, is: How can I dynamically read from the substructure variables - I don't know names and amount of fields there, and values for these fields neither.
I was thinking about repeating the same procedure as for the 'outer' structure, just inside a loop, but since I don't know fields, unlike I do in the outer one .. I cannot create an emptystructure.